# What is the proper way to access data from multiple pages in React Native?

Tags: react-native

So I am working on my first React Native project and I am curious as to what the proper way to handle user data is. I have 3 different pages that are: HomePage, ProfilePage, ChatPage. When a user logs in it navigates them to the HomePage.

As of now, I have it to where when the HomePage loads it makes a backend call that retrieves all of the user data and sets it to some states.

Now when the user navigates to a new page like the ProfilePage none of the data is there anymore of course so do I have to make another backend call? So one backend call for each page? Im sure there has to be some way to only make the backend call once. Could I possibly set a global state of some sort? Should I save all the user data to AsyncStorage?

My current File structure is as follows:

```
App.js -> Contains my React Navigation stack
HomePage.js
ProfilePage.js
ChatPage.js
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you using any state management library? Have you considered using Redux?

Comment: Hard to answer what is "proper" but you should look for a react native state management framework and compare the pros and cons of them for your own needs. Here is a good link to get you started: https://areknawo.com/top-5-react-state-management-libraries-in-late-2020/

Answer (score 2):

You can use Redux plus React-Redux.

To say in short redux is a state management library for react. The states will be global to your app accessible across various components inside app. also there will be reactivity.

For more info visit this link

https://react-redux.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

You should use React-Redux and manage your states globally.